# Customise UITabBar (background image) via subclassing and overriding initWithFrame

Tags: objective-c, uitabbar

There seems to be a lot of different ways to change the appearance of a UITabBar. I found that in iOS 5, there are new properties of the UITabBar such as `backgroundImage`. However, how and where do I set this?

I would like to subclass UITabBar and override the `initWithFrame` method, setting the background image.

Although I have created a new class `@interface UITabBarClass : UITabBar` and in the implementation of `initWithFrame` added the following code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        // Change background image
        UIImage *backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"uitabbar-background-normal"];

        self.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }
    return self;
}
```

the background image does not change. I have also tried writing a log in the same method and it does not get logged at run time.

Can anyone help or give advice?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by following this tutorial, please note that you do not need to create 'tabBar1' as it says, just use `self.tabBar`: http://www.jondack.com/index.php/2010/12/16/customizing-the-background-of-a-uitabbarcontroller/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage....];
```

tabBarController being the name of your Tab Bar Controller.